# Как изменить директорию выполнения модуля, в стороннем приложении

Tags: c++

Возможно ли поменять - директорию выполнения модуля для приложения, к которому нету исходного кода. Товарищ скинул примерное пособие https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, но в нем не очень понятно объясняется, нету наглядного примера, к чему следует внедряться - к самому приложению, либо инжектить виндовские функции ? Объясните пожалуйста !

Comment: А что такое «директория выполнения модуля»? По вашей ссылке объясняются директории для поиска DLL.

Comment: @VladD приложение использует модуль в той же папке где и выполняется. Т.е если C:\folder\My.exe имеет в таблице импортов ссылка на модуль My.dll, он будет его искать в C:\Folder\ . Мне бы хотелось это изменить ! Если можете подобрать по проще - выражение, отредактируйте .

Comment: Окей. Тогда не совсем понятно, зачем вам это. Потому что поиск сначала в каталоге программы происходит для безопасности. Зачем вам нужно отключить безопасность? Если юзер знает о проблеме, вы можете попросить его заменить My.dll на вашу. Если вы хотите обойти безопасность без ведома пользователя, тут что-то не так.

Comment: @VladD Скажем так я как раз хочу чтобы безопасность оставалась, поскольку мой модуль который я передам пользователю захотят взломать, а если я буду генерировать его под не стандартным именем, в разных деректориях, то найти его будет проблематично( не зная куда и когда он копируется)

Comment: Окей, то есть My.dll — это ваш модуль? Тогда не кладите его вовсе в C:\folder\, а положите куда-нибудь в %PATH%, и он подхватится.

Comment: @VladD да мой, и у меня он закидывается следующим образом     `HandleW = CreateFileA(folderPath+ "\\ent.dll",
     GENERIC_WRITE,
     0,
     NULL,
     CREATE_ALWAYS,
     FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY,
     NULL);`  имейте ввиду что должно быть просто `CreateFile(folderPath) `? Дело просто в том что в основном приложении - ожидается именно ent.dll

Comment: Я имею в виду вот что: (1) находите каталог, который есть в %PATH% и доступен для записи вам. (2) записываете туда (а не в каталог с программой) вашу DLL. (3) процесс должен её подхватывать. При этом, понятно, в каталоге с процессом другой DLL с таким же именем быть не должно.

Comment: @VladD что я не очень понял, вот к примеру каталог имеет вид `"C:\Program Files (x86)\BNS"` , в нем `app.exe`, как мне следует тогда создавать файл `CreateFileA("C:\Program Files (x86)\BNS" + "ent.dll") `если так то вместо ent.dll создается BNSent.dll ?

Comment: Вы кажется забыли добавить бекслеш после имени каталога.

Comment: @Vladd Ну так если я его добавлю, модуль BNSent.dll будет записан в каталог, а этого не хочу .

Comment: @Vladd - если есть опасность реверса кода твоей dll, то есть очень много программ(обфускаторов), которые защитят твою dll от реверс-инженеринга, так что можешь свободно протектить свою dll и класть в директорию по умолчанию, а не прятать ее непонятно куда

Comment: @Duracell: Я вообще не боюсь за реверс своих DLL, и пишу на C#. Код, тем более декомпилированный код, без команды, которая умеет его разрабатывать и поддерживать, не стоит ничего.